# Elastic Search : How to have 2 parallel version of ES and configure it to use newer version

Tags: elasticsearch, centos

I have installed and configured "1.7.2" version of elastic search. Now 2.0 version is released.

For time being, I want to have both directories (1.7.2 and 2.0) and want ES to use 2.0 version.

When I start ES, and access app, UI still shows 1.7.2 version. Basically auto discovery for newer version directory is not happening.

Can you please let me know how can I have ES point to 2.0 version directory. (I know 1 solution of running command and providing .yml path in parameter. Any other better solution)

```
/elasticsearch -fD es.config=/usr/local/es/elasticsearch/2.0/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

Comment: What do you mean by "version directory"?

Comment: default directory created after unzip of elastic search is based on version. Example: If version is 2.2.0, directory name will be elasticsearch-2.2.0.
Now I have 2 directories "elasticsearch-1.7.7" and "elasticsearch-2.2.0". 
How can I configure ES to use 2.2.0 version?

Comment: [You can't configure ES to "use" a full installation directory](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-dir-layout.html). If you want to go from 1.7 to 2.x and **keep** the same indices you had and the same data in them, perform an [upgrade](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/restart-upgrade.html). If you want to have both versions on the same machine and to both run at the same time, change the cluster names. But you can't point ES 2.x to 1.x directory, that's not how it works.